# YouTube initialization error

Tags: android, youtube-api

I cannot find out what my error is.
Three days ago my youtubePlayer worked fine in my Android app.
Now I get an initialization error.

I have not changed any code.

here is the stack trace:

> blackstone.tvsunnahboxmenu E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error creating YouTubePlayerView
>                                                                                                 com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w$a: Exception thrown by invoked constructor in com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>                                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
>                                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper class.
>                                                                                                     at wal.a(SourceFile:76)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.(SourceFile:145)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
>   06-30 17:07:48.867 32407-32407/software.blackstone.tvsunnahboxmenu E/SRIB_DCS:  Returning true for title=Toast

```
blackstone.tvsunnahboxmenu E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error creating YouTubePlayerView                                                                                 com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w$a: Exception thrown by invoked constructor in com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)                                                                                                  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper<T> class.                                                                                                  at wal.a(SourceFile:76)
```

Comment: Something has clearly changed if it worked before: your stack trace says "`The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly one declared private field for the wrapped object. Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper class. at wal.a(SourceFile:76)`". Likely that file changed.

Comment: I have not changed this code for the YoutUbe player call.

Comment: I went and pulled the code from my git hub account which has not been touched since May 7th )I have been working locally since then). I down-loaded it and ran it as is - with no changes or edits....  and the same results occur. I have ran it on 4 different android devices and the same result - YT player fails to initialize

Comment: I have rebuilt and cleaned the project as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the project, cleaned the history (cache) and redid the code from the last known good point (within is a life saver!!).

Now it works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

and YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar add to app/libs folder and sync now project

Comment: @ Dholakiya Madhuri: it is in extremely poor taste and manners to just down vote something and add an unexplained comment just to get points. This is not beneficial for anyone and it is poor etiquette and manners between us as software developers. You cause more harm than good when you do things like this. And as a CTO of a company, I would make certain not to hire a person who does this as they would be an obstacle to positive team group and would like the skills to contribute positively to the team.  YES - CTOs, CEOs and tech managers do use stack overflow for help and hiring! we look too!